# Although Rust's char supports non-English characters, many articles recommend using string to store non-English characters instead of char. Why?

Tags: rust, utf-8

I know that Rust's char stores a hexadecimal unicode 4 byte code.

And string (mostly) by UTF-8 (it is recompiled Unicode).

Those articles seemed to express to me that using char to store non-English characters is easy to make mistakes. But I couldn't find any actual code that would cause trouble.

I checked the basics knowledge of Unicode, UTF8, UTF32. But I still don’t understand that this approach is not recommended

According to my understanding, when ensuring that the code file is compiled with UTF-8, char and string are used to store non-English characters at the same time, and they should all be compiled correctly.

Rust doc did not say that it cannot be used. But he cited a non-English character, which can be represented by one Unicode code point or two Unicode code points. It also stated that a human intuition for ‘character’ may not map to Unicode’s definitions
Because of my language problem, my local article added the point of using STRING instead of char to store non-English characters as much as possible on this basis. (But he didn't have any specific instructions. All the articles I saw are like this)
é can directly use the Unicode code point occupied by the Latin text itself, or use the English e and an acute accent.
Can this cause any problems? If I use char to store é. I should always get one Unicode code point. Why should I care about precomposed character

Comment: If there are so many articles like that, you could maybe link one or two as examples, then others could verify what the articles are trying to say and maybe explain it.

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer Thank you for reminding I was going to do that ,but I'm not sure . those articles are not in English .Those articles are just saying that the character concept of RUST's char is counter-intuitive, (this is the same as the rust document). Then there is no other explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can have a look at the explanation from [*UTF-8 Everywhere*](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

To brief it, what you see as a “character” is often NOT a `char`. A `char` is a *code point*, while a (visual) character is far more complicated than that. I quote from the above-mentioned site (emphases are mine):

> Encoded character, Coded character — A mapping between a code point and an abstract character.[§3.4, D11] For example, U+1F428 is a coded character which represents the abstract character  koala.
> **This mapping is neither total, nor injective, nor surjective**:
>
> - **Surrogates, noncharacters and unassigned code points do not correspond to abstract characters at all.**
> - **Some abstract characters can be encoded by different code points**; U+03A9 greek capital letter omega and U+2126 ohm sign both correspond to the same abstract character `Ω`, and must be treated identically.
> - **Some abstract characters cannot be encoded by a single code point.** These are represented by sequences of coded characters. For example, the only way to represent the abstract character `ю́` cyrillic small letter yu with acute is by the sequence U+044E cyrillic small letter yu followed by U+0301 combining acute accent.
>
> Moreover, **for some abstract characters, there exist representations using multiple code points, in addition to the single coded character form.** The abstract character `ǵ` can be coded by the single code point U+01F5 latin small letter g with acute, or by the sequence `<U+0067 latin small letter g, U+0301 combining acute accent>`.

Do check the site for more details and insights.

---

Since you specifically asked about the problems for using a `char` instead of the more generic `String`/`str`, I will try to name some:

1. There is actually some characters that can only be represented as multiple code points (e.g. some emoji characters);
2. Even if you managed to store one in a `char`, you don’t have too much to gain. A `&str` should be light-weight enough;
3. If you ever want to receive input from the user, you had better use a `String`, for you would never know how the “character” is encoded;
4. Personally, use a `str`/`String` is a reminder: text processing is always hard, and the complication in “character” is only a small part.

Comment: Therefore, char cannot store "character which only be represented as multiple code points" (Unless by special way).
And for "characters that can be represented by one or two encoding point" , cause the user's input encoding problem , the program may get two encoding point instead of one. This will make char not work .Or when the program compares whether the characters are equal, it will get the wrong result.  that's right?

Comment: I have no idea about the way to use char to express character which must by mult unicode point (splice two chars into one? maybe?)
whatever , I think I get it. appreciate it!  XD

Comment: @food_honey Correct. Usually when processing texts, especially when interfacing with the user, requiring the input to fit in “a code point” (and thus a `char`) would be rather arbitrary and confusing. The general recommendation is to use UTF-8 encoded strings for text processing for their space efficiency and generality.

Comment: The fact that a "character" is an easily misunderstood concept with several competing definitions is one of the fundamental tricky aspects of Unicode (and not really related to UTF-8). The basic idea is that what a *user* would consider a "character" can span over multiple bytes and even multiple codepoints. So a good general rule is: don't try to count (or in some other way manipulate) characters in a Unicode string on your own, there's a good chance you'll get at least some corner cases wrong. Use a dedicated library (like ICU) to do that for you.

Comment: Rust [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/index.html) say: `char` is a ‘[Unicode scalar value](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value)’, which is similar to, but not the same as, a ‘[Unicode code point](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_point)’.